# unexpected T-string in line 8

Tags: php

i get the following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a5836790/public_html/3.1 opdracht.php on line 8

from script:

```
<?php
$vars = array(true, 10, 19.95, 'hoi');
$var = array2(1 is van het type, 10 is van het type, 19.95 is van het type, text is van het type);
foreach ($vars as $waarde) {
    foreach ($var as $waardes) {
        echo gettype($waarde), "\n";
        echo $waardes, "\n"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Can any1 help me out on this issue,

i cant figure it out.

Comment: @SumitGupta As mentioned in response to one of the answers below, the commas are actually valid - they are passing multiple parameters to the echo statement, which is actually slightly more efficient than concatenating them together into one string in memory.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
$vars = array(true, 10, 19.95, 'hoi');
$var = array('1 is van het type', '10 is van het type', '19.95 is van het type', 'text is van het type');
foreach ($vars as $waarde) {
    foreach ($var as $waardes) {
        echo gettype($waarde). "\n";
        echo $waardes. "\n"; 
    }
}
?>
```

`array2` is not valid array function. It will be `array`

if value of array is string it must be include with quote `('')`.

Comment: It's best if you include in your answer an explanation of what you have changed and why, rather than making the OP play "Spot the Difference".

Comment: @IMSoP Ok Now explain what i change. fist I change `array2` as `array`. because array2 is not a array function. Then I change the value of array with quote because string must be include with quote

Comment: I didn't mean explain it to me, I meant edit your answer to include this information.

Comment: do I know why I get minus

Comment: That was me, for the reasons already stated: a good answer includes an explanation.

Comment: @IMSoP Now I explain what I change

Answer (score 0):

Use dots instead of commas for concatenation.

```
echo gettype($waarde). "\n";
echo $waardes. "\n";
```

And this line...

```
$var = array2(1 is van het type, 10 is van het type, 19.95 is van het type, text is van het type);
```

...well, there's so much wrong with it, I don't know where to begin.

Comment: The commas are actually valid - they are not concatenating the string, but passing multiple parameters to the `echo` statement. It's actually slightly more efficient that way, as it doesn't need to allocate memory for the concatenated string.

Answer (score 0):

The line it's complaining about is this one:

```
$var = array2(1 is van het type, 10 is van het type, 19.95 is van het type, text is van het type);
```

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to with that line, but assuming you want to create an array, the keyword is always `array`, not `array2`; `array2` could be the name of a function, but I don't think that's what you meant.

You also have a series of phrases in that array which aren't quoted as strings. This is the syntax error PHP is complaining about - it's getting as far as `is` and not knowing what it means. You need to put quotes around each set of words you want to be a separate string, so I think what you want is this:

```
$var = array('1 is van het type', '10 is van het type', '19.95 is van het type', 'text is van het type');
```